# how to implement server side using java for android app

Tags: java, android

I m developing android app and it has loging process. I send loging details using http request as json object. How i implement server side using java for getting json object and send response to android app.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Since you are looking for java server side. You can take a look at jsp servlets, web frameworks like spring mvc etc.. You have to deploy it in web server like tomcat, jboss etc.. Start with googling and read basics to start with..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set up a server with some sort of scripting language that takes the request and does whatever you want with the data. Languages such as Ruby, Python, and PHP are probably the most widely used for this.

Your question is extremely broad and unspecific so it is hard to give much more advice than that.